# Drupal Facebook Comments Box positionning

Tags: drupal, facebook-comments

I have recently added a Facebook Comments Box to my Drupal site, in order to allow users to comment my articles with their facebook accounts.

The problem is that I can't change the position of the box : I want it to be at the end of the page, after the article content, but it stays between the title and the content of the article...

I've tried to put an absolute positon with CSS, but I don't like to do it this way, because it's not very sweet :

[image: bug illustration]

**EDIT**: I solved my problem by putting manually the facebook comments box content into the template node.tpl.php, like this :

```
<article>
...
<?php if (!strstr($classes,"node-teaser")) : ?>
<br><br>
<div id="fb-root" class=" fb_reset">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0px; width: 0px;">
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="position: absolute; top: -10000px; height: 0px; width: 0px;">
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:comments href="http://localhost/Studio 107/?q=node/<?php print $node->nid; ?>" width="700" num_posts="10" colorscheme="dark" fb-xfbml-state="rendered" class="fb_iframe_widget">
  </span>
</fb:comments>
```

Comment: u can post it as a answer

Answer (score 2):

Facebook Comment Box adds a block. Go to Structure -> Blocks. Find the region where this block is placed.Drag and reorder the Comment Block so its at the bottom of all the blocks in that specific region.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the other major Facebook comments module in Drupal: Facebook Comments Social Plugin. The module gives you the ability to output the comments not only via block but also a field on the node's Manage Display options. You can even output the comments via a template (TPL) file. Here's a tutorial/walkthrough on [how to integrate Facebook comments in Drupal](http://www.daymuse.com/blogs/drupal-facebook-comments-social-plugin-module-tutorial); it's fairly quick to setup the module.